# Javascript passing variable on trigger events for twitter callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am using twitter share button with callback functionality , I have implemented like this,

```
var tweetUrlBuilder = function(o){
        return [
            'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?tw_p=tweetbutton',
            '&url=', encodeURI(o.url),
            '&via=', o.via,
            '&text=', o.text
        ].join('');
    };


    function Tweet(post_id, post_title){
    console.log(post_id);
    console.log(post_title);
    var job_title = job_title;
    var url = tweetUrlBuilder({
        url : window.location.href,
        via : 'TaqiOfficial',
        text: post_title
    });
    window.open(url, 'Tweet', 'height=500,width=700');
}

var callback = function(e){
    if(e && e.data){
        var data;
        try{
            data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        }catch(e){
            // Don't care.
        }
        if(data && data.params && data.params.indexOf('tweet') > -1){
            console.log('Tweeted Successfully');
            console.log(post_title);
        }
    }
};

window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener("message", callback, !1) : window.attachEvent("onmessage",callback)
```

I am trying to get `post_title` when tweet has been successfully made, but I am unable to get it.

Comment: where do you attach your callback function? is your function being called at all? what exactly do you mean by `unable to get it`?

Comment: @muratgu Scroll down and you will see... and the twitter library works with `postMessage`s, and he is trying to hack into the system manually.

Comment: It's working well, and also printed my msg on console `tweeted successfully`. but i wan to access `var post_title` from `Tweet function` here